# TFS 2010 table schema

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a report using TFS 2010 database to show all Work Items that have been updated between 2 labels.  I have found the tbl_Label and WorkItemsLatest tables, but don't know how to join the two together.  Does anyone know which additional tables I need to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Labels in TFS do not state a point in time, they may actually contain a mix of items, each with their own versionspec. So you can't join "the label" directly with time data.

What you could do is use the label creation dates and join using that dates on the ticket changed dates. I recommend you take a look at the cube databases instead of the actual production database, as the cube databases often have a much clearer layout, because they do not have to be speed optimized for the regular TFS work.